# Advanced (maybe) selection rule for lists in Python

Tags: python, loops

Given are a list

```
list_ = [a,a,b,b,b,a,b,a,b,b,...,b]
```

and two other lists

```
l_a = [v1,v2,...,vN]
l_B = [w1,w2,...,wN].
```

The first element of list_ is always "`a`". The remaining elements can be mixed up between being "`a`" and "`b`" in any random way.

Now, starting from the first element in list_ (which is always "a"):

1. Take elements from `l_a` until you hit a "`b`" (in this case: [v1,
   v2]). Form "`v1+v2`" as a key for a dictionary (the corresponding value is in step 2. below). This is our current key.
2. Take elements from l_b until you hit an "a" (in this case just [w1,w2,w3]). Store "`w1 + w2 + w3`" as value under the current key.
3. *Repeat*.

Of course, there is a lot of loop stuff going on that I tried, but it just quickly gets difficult to bookkeep and makes me think there is a better way than nesting loops.

**Question:**
So, simply put, how do I do this in an efficient way?

Thank you

Comment: So, the total number of a's will be equal to the length of l_a, and the total number of b's will be equal to the length of l_B?

Comment: Why the down vote? I've seen many more stupid questions not down voted!

Comment: An example input and output would greatly clarify your question. As noted in one of the answers below, `itertools.groupby` will probably be paramount in a succinct solution.

Comment: @sberry yes that is correct

Comment: @denvar In that case I think my answer solves your issue.  I wasn't entirely sure what you wanted to do with the data (you mentioned things like "`v1+v2`" but I didn't know if that was concatenating strings or adding numbers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will give you some ideas.

What you really want to do is group together the repeated items (itertools.groupby is great for that) then remove the items from the head of the list (you could also leave the lists alone and just maintain an index of your current position and do slicing).

```
import itertools
import random
import collections

choices = ['a', 'b']

list_ = [random.choice(choices) for _ in range(30)]

l_a = collections.deque([random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(list_.count('a'))])
l_b = collections.deque([random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(list_.count('b'))])

# Everything above is to build up the sample data.
# You can wrap your existing l_a, l_B lists in a collections.deque

# make a dictionary that holds the two dequeues keyed by the character we find in list_
lists_by_char = {'a': l_a, 'b': l_b}

# print it out to make sure we aren't cheating
print(list_)
print(l_a)
print(l_b)

for k, g in itertools.groupby(list_):
    # k will be the letter 'a' or 'b'
    # g will be the items in a _grouper.  We can call list on that to get the actual items.  But what we care about is the length of that list.
    items = [lists_by_char.get(k).popleft() for _ in range(len(list(g)))]
    # The we call popleft on the deque matching our current character as many times as our list of characters is long.
    print(k, items)
```

Example output - will vary each time you run it

```
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a']
deque([36, 61, 7, 17, 25, 76, 2, 72, 15, 33, 1, 53, 54, 49, 29, 68])
deque([55, 95, 97, 24, 72, 14, 54, 98, 91, 98, 57, 56, 40, 17])
a [36, 61]
b [55, 95, 97]
a [7, 17, 25]
b [24]
a [76]
b [72, 14]
a [2]
b [54, 98, 91]
a [72, 15, 33, 1, 53]
b [98, 57]
a [54, 49]
b [56, 40, 17]
a [29, 68]
```

Comment: I'm still confused about the question in general, but `itertools.groupby` seems like it's going to be a big part of any elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another similar approach:

```
list_ = "aabbbababbb"
n_a = [len(x) for x in list_.split('b') if x!='']
n_b = [len(x) for x in list_.split('a') if x!='']
```

This will give you the numbers of consecutive `a`'s and `b`'s. You can then use that to sum over and create your keys. Note: using `np.cumsum(zip(n_a ,n_b))` should give you the relevant indices to sum over.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reasonably simple solution:

```
# given
a = "A"
b = "B"
l = [a,a,b,b,b,a,b,a,b,b,b] # ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B']
l_a = range(0, 2*len(l), 2) # [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
l_b = range(1, 2*len(l)+1, 2) # [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21]

d = {}
making_l_a_key = True
making_l_b_val = False
key = ()
value = []

for index, item in enumerate(l):
    if item == a and making_l_b_val:
        making_l_a_key = True
        making_l_b_val = False
        d[tuple(key)] = value
        key = ()
        value = []

    if item == b and making_l_a_key:
        making_l_a_key = False
        making_l_b_val = True

    if item == a and making_l_a_key:
        key += (l_a[index], )
    if item == b and making_l_b_val:
        value.append(l_b[index])

d[key] = value

print d
```

Output:

```
{(10,): [13], (0, 2): [5, 7, 9], (14,): [17, 19, 21]}
```